# confirm only one time function with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this function. if is confirmed the second time i will not want to ask again!

```
jQuery('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {

            if(rel == max || rel < max) {
                sec(jQuery(this).attr('rel'), jQuery(this).val());
            }

            var names = {};
            jQuery(':radio').each(function() {
                names[jQuery(this).attr('name')] = true;
            });
            var count = 0;
            jQuery.each(names, function() { 
                count++;
            });

            var confirmed = false;
            if (jQuery(':radio:checked').length === count) {
                if(confirmed || confirm("Bütün soruları cevapladınız testi bitirelim mi ?")) {
                    jQuery('#FinishTest').trigger('click');
                    confirmed = true;   
                }   else {
                    confirmed = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

confirmed dosent work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var confirmed` is not global, so it is resetting on every click, make it global, by putting it out side the click callback:

```
var confirmed = false;

jQuery('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {

        if(rel == max || rel < max) {
            sec(jQuery(this).attr('rel'), jQuery(this).val());
        }

        var names = {};
        jQuery(':radio').each(function() {
            names[jQuery(this).attr('name')] = true;
        });
        var count = 0;
        jQuery.each(names, function() { 
            count++;
        });


        if (jQuery(':radio:checked').length === count) {
            if(confirmed || confirm("Bütün soruları cevapladınız testi bitirelim mi ?")) {
                jQuery('#FinishTest').trigger('click');
                confirmed = true;   
            }   else {
                confirmed = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you I solved the problem. I work a lot, I guess. I missed it.